# How to disable new architecture in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have recently enabled new architecture in `iOS` by running following command

```
RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 pod install
```

I would like to disable it now, But unable to figure out a way. I couldn't find anything from official documentation as well.

Is there anyway to disable the new architecture or creating the new project is the only way?

Thank You.

Comment: RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=0 bundle exec pod install

Comment: @Iva it's not working. Still project is with new architecture. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run this command:

`RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=0 pod install`